# Import JS class inside AngularJS Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have two separat JS-files: an AngularJS(1.4x) Controller `someController.js`, and `custom-class.js`, which contains the class `CustomClass`.

I would like to access `CustomClass` and its functions from within the Controller.

Can that be achieved by using `import` inside the Controller and `export` in the corresponding file?
If not, what options do I have, instead?

Comment: I'll try to use the class as a script, by including it in my `index.html`.

Comment: I tried passing the Class to a Service, and then use it in said controller.
I ran into some trouble with that, which I described in another Post:
[Passing a JS Class to an AngularJS Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58601337/passing-a-js-class-to-angular-service-to-use-its-variables-and-functions)