# Passing a JS-Class to AngularJS(1.4.x) service to use its variables and functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I use angularJS(1.4) for frontend only.

I have passed the JS-class `DummyClass` to an angularJS-Service called `TLSService`, and I added this service to an angularJS-Controller named `mLxController`.

I'm having problems accessing variables and methods of the `DummyClass` from the `mLxController`.
For example, as you will see in the code below, I can't retrieve a class variable String.
I use `window.alert(String)` to check that. 
Instead of the String from the `DummyClass`, 'undefined' is displayed in the window.

I think it's worth mentioning, that when adding the `window.alert("DummyClass calls.")` in the `constructor` of the `DummyClass`, the `alert` will immedialtely be shown after loading the corresponding URL.

That's the code of the `mLxController.js` :

```
angular.module('mApp')
.controller('mLxController', function('TLSService', $scope, $state, $stateParams){
...
//this function is called in `index.html`
$scope.callTLSService = function(){
  window.alert(TLSService.response);
}
...
});
```

Here's the code for `dummyClass.js` :

```
class DummyClass {  
  constructor() {
    this.response = "Hi Controller! Service told me you were looking for me.";
  }
}
```

Here's `tlsService.js` :

```
angular.module('mApp').service('TestClaServScript', function(){new DummyClass()});
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I have managed to make the `DummyClass` usable to the `mLxController`.
Although I'm pretty sure that my solution is not recommendable practice.

Basically, I moved the DummyClass into the same file as the `TLSService`.
Also, `DummyClass` and it's path isn't mentioned in the main index.html, anymore.

Accordingly, `tlsService.js` looks like this, now:

```
angular.module('mApp').service('TestClaServScript', function(){

    this.clConnect = function(inStr){

        var mDummy = new DummyClass(inStr);
        return mDummy;
    }
});


class DummyClass {

    constructor(inStr){
        this.inStr = inStr;
        this.response = 
            "DummyClass says: \"Hi Controller! Service told me you were looking for me.\"";
        this.charCount = function(inStr){
            var nResult = inStr.length;
            var stRes = "btw, your String has "
            +(nResult-1)+", "+nResult+", or "+(nResult+1)+" characters.\nIDK."
            return stRes;
        }
    }
}
```

and  `mLxController.js`:

```
angular.module('mApp')
.controller('mLxController', function('TLSService',$scope,$state, $stateParams){
...
$scope.makeDummyCount = function(){
      var mDummy = TestClaServScript.clConnect("This string is for counting");
      window.alert(mDummy.charCount(mDummy.inStr));
  }
...
});
```

There must be a way to properly import `DummyClass`, so that I can keep separate files.
I will do some more research and I will keep trying.

---

**UPDATE 2: Problem solved**

The provided answer to my question helped me implementing `TLSService` in the originally planned way.

I'd like to post the final version of the code here, in hope that it will help some beginner, like I am.

`tlsService.js`:

```
angular.module('mApp').service('TLSService', function(){
    this.mCwParam =  function(inputStr){
        return new DummyClass(inputStr);
    }
});
```

`DummyClass` stays the same like I posted it in the first Update, but it has its own file `dummyClass.js`, again.

`mLxController.js`:

```
angular.module('mApp')
.controller('mLxController', function('TLSService', $scope, $state, $stateParams){
...
//this function is called in the mLx-view's `index.html`
$scope.askDummyCount = function(){
  var mService = TLSService.mCwParam("String, string, string, and all the devs that sing.");
  window.alert(mService.charCount());
}
...
});
```

Also, `TLSService` and `DummyClass` ar added in the apps main `index.html`.

Comment: i think the issue is, that using a separate class through a Service is not provided in angularJS v.1.4.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem in your original setup is when you register your class as a service, you're not returning the instance of the class:

```
function(){new DummyClass()}
```

Should be:

```
function(){return new DummyClass()}
```

Autoreturning only works when you don't use curly braces, like

```
() => new DummyClass()
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will try this in 30 minutes. 
I've seen code with the same `() => new Class()` arrow function. I translated it, because I thought I read, that `Arrow Functions` shouldn't be use with `constructors` or with the `new` statement. I have to update my knowledge on that.
Anyway, `return` got lost in translation.

Comment: You can't use an arrow function as a constructor because its `this` pointer would be invalid, but I haven't heard of any problems using them to `new` objects.

Comment: Thanks, again! Works at least without passing arguments from Controller to Service.
Now, I will try implementing the same with a `constructor` that receives arguments. Back to the books!